# PHP Object giving values to a string from a mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php

```
public static function instantiate($record){
     $object = new self;


    // $object->id = $record['UserID'];
    // $object->username = $record['Username'];
    // $object->password = $record['Password'];
    // $object->first_name = $record['Fname'];
    // $object->last_name = $record['Lname'];
    // $object->email = $record['Email'];

    foreach (array_unique($record) as $attribute => $value) {

        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){

            $object->$attribute = $value;
            //var_dump($attribute);echo '<br>';
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

In this function i get values from this $object in two ways. The long way from the commented part and the short way from the uncommented (obv).

The long way gives the good result as this :

> object(User)#5 (6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(6) "Parley" ["password"]=> string(5) "12345" ["first_name"]=> string(8) "Cristian" ["last_name"]=> string(8) "Pirloaga" ["email"]=> string(27) "cristian.pirloaga@gmail.com" }

The short way gives a bad result as this :

> int(0) 
>   int(1) 
>   int(2) 
>   int(3) 
>   int(4) 
>   int(5) 
>   int(6) 
>   object(User)#5 (13) { ["id"]=> NULL ["username"]=> NULL ["password"]=> NULL ["first_name"]=> NULL ["last_name"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["0"]=> string(1) "1" ["1"]=> string(8) "Cristian" ["2"]=> string(8) "Pirloaga" ["3"]=> string(27) "cristian.pirloaga@gmail.com" ["4"]=> string(6) "Parley" ["5"]=> string(5) "12345" ["6"]=> string(19) "2016-02-12 05:04:22" }

the int(1)..int(6) are the $attribute values, after is the object.

Im trying to match the $attribute values with those fields from the long way. How can i do it?
This is an actually code from a tutorial and it works to him and not to me.

I have a secondary issue. The foreach loop always double the values.In this case if i remove the array_unique function it will show that result two times tho in data base its only one row.why's that?

Comment: I know it is not your question, but if you want an object containing your data use `mysqli_fetch_object` instead of  `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the result you want by using `mysqli_fetch_object` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`.

But to answer your question: If you use `mysqli_fetch_array`, by default you get an array containing numeric keys and associative keys as well. For example something like:

```
array(
 1 => 'john',
 2 => 'doe',
 'firstname' => 'john',
 'lastname' => 'doe'
)
```

To avoid that you can set the third parameter `int $result_type` to `MYSQL_ASSOC` as described here: 
http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Using `MYSQL_ASSOC` you will get an array without numeric keys, for example:

```
array(
 'firstname' => 'john',
 'lastname' => 'doe'
)
```

Doing that your function will work, even without the `array_unique` in the foreach.

Comment: Width MYSQLI_ASSOC i get this bad result : string(6) "UserID" 
string(5) "Fname" 
string(5) "Lname" 
string(5) "Email" 
string(8) "Username" 
string(8) "Password" 
string(9) "Timestamp" 
object(User)#5 (13) { ["id"]=> NULL ["username"]=> NULL ["password"]=> NULL ["first_name"]=> NULL ["last_name"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL ["UserID"]=> string(1) "1" ["Fname"]=> string(8) "Cristian" ["Lname"]=> string(8) "Pirloaga" ["Email"]=> string(27) "cristian.pirloaga@gmail.com" ["Username"]=> string(6) "Parley" ["Password"]=> string(5) "12345" ["Timestamp"]=> string(19) "2016-02-12 05:04:22" }

Comment: thanks alot Mario A for the mysql_object alternative. now im following this tutorial with how it does but forsure at the end ill do this upgrade.